# Sending attachments with mailx and uuencode

Tags: linux, bash, ksh, uuencode

I am in the process of trying to run a ksh script which usually sits on an AIX machine on its new host Linux node.

The code I am running looks like this:

```
 (uuencode $path/info.dat info.csv; uuencode $RESULTS results.log) | mail -s "Info" $MAIL_RECIPIENTS
```

This normally sends an email with the subject "Info" and contains the attachments info.csv and results.log.

However on my Linux machine this isn't happening - it is sending the email with the uuencode output as the body of the email and no attachments:

```
begin 775 info.csv

M+3`U+C`S+C4S+C(Q-#`W."(L(D%55$]314Y$("`B+")!551/4T5.1"`@(BPB
etc..
etc...
end

begin 775 results.log
M+3`U+C`S+C4S+C(Q-#`W."(L(D%55$]314Y$("`B+")!551/4T5.1"`@(BPB
etc...
etc...
end
```

I have tried to just send the files as attachments without using uuencode at all:

```
mail -a info.csv -a results.log -s "Info" $MAIL_RECIPIENTS
```

But this is being invoked in the middle of a script and it just hangs unless I CTRL D.

This is the version of uuencode I am using:

```
uuencode (GNU sharutils) 4.7
Copyright (C) 1994, 1995, 1996, 2002, 2005, 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Has anyone else experienced this? I am afraid **mutt** is not an option.

Comment: try `echo "" | mail -a ....` Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the body of the email was empty anyway I was able to do this to stop the mail utility hanging waiting for EOT.

```
mail -a info.cvs -a results.log -s "Info" $MAIL_RECIPIENTS < /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mailx for sending a mail with body and attachment and use it like this:

```
$ echo "body" | mailx -a AttachmentFile -s "subject" recipient@somewhere.com
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
uuencode info.cvs info.cvs |mailx -s 'results.log' -r $ReplyAddress $MailAddress
```